# Issues with installing Ruby 2.0.0 on macOS Catalina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I'm running to issue installing Ruby 2.0.0 on a new macbook with macOS Catalina (version 10.15.7). At first I installed Ruby with rvm which did not work. I figured out that it was because Catalina's default terminal is ZSH instead of Bash (https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina). I was able to install Ruby 2.6.3 with the instructions but the issue is that the project I'm currently working on was written in Ruby 2.0.0. I tried installing this version with `rbenv install 2.0.0-p0` but I ran to the following errors:

```
ruby-build: using libyaml from homebrew
Downloading openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/ecd0c6ffb493dd06707d38b14bb4d8c2288bb7033735606569d8f90f89669d16
Installing openssl-1.0.2u...
Installed openssl-1.0.2u to /Users/vydoan/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0

Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p0.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p0...

WARNING: ruby-2.0.0-p0 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (Mac OS X 10.15.7 using ruby-build 20201005)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/m4/3k5xfdwx7x7gqkzzlyrlc_gc0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201006082731.4615.0q3Cat
Results logged to /var/folders/m4/3k5xfdwx7x7gqkzzlyrlc_gc0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201006082731.4615.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling cont.c
compiling ./enc/ascii.c
thread.c:928:27: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to '__darwin_suseconds_t' (aka 'int') [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        tp->tv_usec = ts.tv_nsec / 1000;
                    ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
compiling ./enc/us_ascii.c
1 error generated.
make: *** [thread.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 warning generated.
```

I've tried doing the follow:

1.

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

which gives me this error log

```
Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.
```

2. 

```
brew install gcc
```

3. 

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p0
```

which gives me the same errors as above.

I've asked my team and found that another person also have issue with installing ruby on their new mac machines. The older mac didn't not have this problem. Was anyone able to successfully install Ruby 2.0.0 on the newer mac?

Comment: FWIW, ZSH should work fine with RVM. I just installed Ruby 2.0.0 on my machine (Catalina) using RVM and ZSH.

Comment: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1068  There are some helpful things to try in this thread

Comment: @weltschmerz Could you expand on this? What were the script that you ran to install 2.0.0? I tried doing it with rvm again and got this error `Error running '__rvm_make -j12',`

Comment: I just ran `rvm install 2.0.0`. Try updating your rvm `rvm get head` then try again?

Comment: May need to run `rvm reload` after updating.

Comment: FYI, you're not installing "ruby on rails 2.0", you're installing ruby 2.0. Rails version is not locked to Ruby's and Rails 2 is basically ancient at this point.

Comment: @weltschmerz No luck :(. The log gave me the following error:`error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_frame_last_func' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    const ID mid = rb_frame_last_func();`

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: No idea what that error means, would need to google.

Answer (score 3):

Hello I had numerous issues trying to install `ruby 2.2.7` the project I work on has quiet a deprecated version of ruby necessary stated above now I ran into numerous problems they use `rvm` I could not install `2.2.7` using rvm I have however succeeded using `rbenv` the thing that ruins your experience is mainly the command line tools provided by Apple since in newer version it does not support compiling older ruby versions.
I also run the same version of MacOS : [image: Screenshot of MacOs version]

Your best bet (since I've tried several days in a row to get my setup working installing ruby being the biggest blocker).Go to apple's developer site and download an older version of command line tools [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and browse for `11.4.1`(*Before running the next steps make sure to purge previous attempts and ruby version managers and symlinks so it won't interfere with you next install and make your life hard*).
Before downloading and installing it check your `gcc -v` remember that and install the command line tools you've downloaded and check it again to see if things went according to plan you should get something like:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I haven't tried other versions but this one works afterwards go to `rbenv` official website install the tools add the shell scripts to your local `.zshrc` file (if you don't have one just create it).Besides adding what the guide says it ommits an important step you also need to add this to your `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Then you should just close and open the terminal and install the ruby version you need :

```
# list latest stable versions:
$ rbenv install -l

# list all local versions:
$ rbenv install -L

# install a Ruby version:
$ rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

Consult the [docs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#command-reference) as of how to use them globally or locally also if use is not working end all terminal windows and the process restart and it should work just okay.

**!Important mentions is to not change the command line tools when compiling different ruby related version may break the setup (ignore brew messages to update command line tools when running brew doctor)!**